Momentum measurement paradox in a box
We have seen that a momentum eigenstate can be expressed as sum of position eigenstates as: $${| {p} \rangle}= \int{Ae^{i(p/\hbar)\hat{x}}| {x} \rangle}dx$$
Where $A$ is a constant . Suppose we measure the momentum of a particle in a box and the wavefunction collapses to: $${| {p'} \rangle}.$$ We know that the particle cannot be found outside the box (infinite square well)  . Therefore $${Ae^{i(p'/\hbar)\hat{x}}}=0$$ for any $x$ outside the box or at the boundary of the box. And the wavefunction also have to be continuous . The only way it can be guaranteed is by making $A=0$ but then it will be 0 everywhere inside the box also which is not physically possible . So can position be measured for a particle ina box?
EDIT:-
I recently noticed an issue with the phenomenon of wave function collapse . After collapse the wavefunction collapses to a single eigenstate of its respective observable like position or momentum or something else. This means that the wavefunction takes the form of a delta function in that observable space . But we all know that Delta functions are not continuous thus failing the law of QM that wavefunction needs to be continuous

Related: What's the deal with momentum in the infinite square well?

You can't measure the momentum of a particle in a box with infinite precision - that would violate Heisenberg, since $\Delta x$ is always smaller than the size of the box.

@FusRoDah one can't measure any continuous variable with infinite precision already in classical theory, so the fact the momentum has finite uncertainty also due to Heisenberg relations is not really important. Even if there is no box, measurement of a continuous variable is always hampered with finite error.

I recently noticed an issue with the phenomenon of wave function collapse . After collapse the wavefunction collapses to a single eigenstate of its respective observable like position or momentum or something else. This means that the wavefunction takes the form of a delta function in that observable space . But we all know that Delta functions are not continuous thus failing the law of QM that wavefunction needs to be continuous

States in an infinite square well satisfy boundary conditions $\psi(0)=\psi(L)=0$. On the other hand, the state on which you are trying to project does not satisfy these boundary conditions. This is a contradiction in the setup, not in the result of a measurement (or the QM) - it means that your box is not really infinite (not when you measure at least).
In other words: the state on which we project/measure must be a possible state of the system, i.e., satisfying the same boundary conditions (but not necessarily an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian.) If it is not, it means that measurement modifies the system (as we indeed expect in QM), so one shouldn't make the claims based on what system was before the measurement.

The real answer is that the QM framework was designed for ideal situations of measurements at fixed, chosen times $t$. Real measurement situations don't work like that, and the state-after-measurement postulate is known to be in contradiction with experiment. The state after a momentum measurement is not actually a $|p\rangle$ eigenstate, although that might in some way approximate the state after measurement. There are a million issues that can be found with a perfect momentum eigenstate, one of those issues being that it predicts that the particle can be found on the opposite side of the universe faster than light could travel there. $|p\rangle$ gives equal probability everywhere in the universe in position space.
That being said, we don't just "measure momentum" by applying a "momentum measurement" at a fixed time to a particle in whatever state we want. There are a variety of momentum measurement techniques, all of which would require the particle to interact with something more complicated than just an infinite square well box. For example, if the particle is charged, you could let the particle fly out of the box and into a magnetic field, and measure the curvature of the path it flies along. Yes, this is fundamentally a position measurement, but that's how momentum is measured in real life. Actually this one is directly from the ATLAS inner detector.
So, in order to ask questions about states after measurement, you have to have an awareness of what your method of measurement is. Then you can respond just based on the physical system.
I think it's time to re-evaluate those von Neumann postulates & set up more truthful postulates that define the theory.

There is no problem with QM here, but measurement in this case manifestly modifies the system - a finite system is projected on an extended state.

@RogerV. My thought on this is, regardless of the experimental consequences, it would be helpful to improve on the founding postulates of the theory. From a scientific perspective, having a set of (consistent) foundational postulates makes the theory's predictions unique and not open to interpretation, and therefore falsifiable. So I do actually see it as a problem with the theory of QM, considering that there is no widely accepted alternative formulation which A. doesn't have this issue or similar ones, and B. from which all of the results of the standard theory can be derived.

@don'ttrainaionme My understanding is that there is such a formulation of non-relativistic QM: if you look into the Positive-Operator Valued Measure formalism of quantum mechanics, you do away with unphysical "position" and "momentum" operators, and instead represent observables by sets of equivalent projectors onto some Hilbert space. Then, any experimental procedure has an associated POVM which will never result into a state collapsing to a delta function.

@user2506833 POVMs specify probabilities, but not state after measurement

@don'ttrainaionme, but you then have projective measurement, so rather than a state collapsing to a delta function it collapses to some bona fide element of the Hilbert space. You don't run into issues of states leaving the Hilbert space after a measurement.

@user2506833 That doesn't give a solution, because you're just (in different language) saying we should change the state after measurement to some other non-delta-function. That is what a projection onto that state would do. But which state should that be, or how exactly would it be found? There is no agreed-upon answer. This is the issue I mentioned.

@don'ttrainaionme The POVM formalism provides an unambiguous post collapse state without ever involving a delta function. It's given here.

@user2506833 The first sentence of that literally says that the POVM doesn't determine a post collapse state. It's the standard measurement formalism - the PVM - that does. A projective measurement (PVM) on a system looks like a POVM on a subsystem. So this doesn't contribute anything to the post-collapse state beyond the standard measurement (PVM) formalism. You are using very confident phrasing for claims that are on shaky ground.

@don'ttrainaionme You're right, a POVM doesn't uniquely define the density operator post-measurement.

@don'ttrainaionme Regardless, I'm not sure I understand your objection to the projective measurement formalism. It doesn't have the problems described in this question (one cannot realize a PVM corresponding to a "momentum" or "position" measurement) and in principle any experimental apparatus can be described by selecting the appropriate PVM. What's the issue here?

@don'ttrainaionme Nevermind, I just read one of your earlier comments about quantum mechanics modelling continuous measurement and the failure of protective measurement. Interesting!

Right- As for the problems described in this question: The PVMs corresponding to the textbook momentum or position measurement (resulting in delta functions in momentum or position space) are the projectors $|p\rangle \langle p |$ and $|x\rangle \langle x |$, respectively. You can try another PVM (it's been tried), but each is unrealistic in its own way, which is why there's no widely accepted "better" alternative, and why we still have the delta function as a "least ugly option" in textbooks. Still, it's in contradiction with experiment, so that's not something to be satisfied with long-term.

I don't see why you think the ket for a state with definite momentum $|p'\rangle$ is a sum over some position kets $|x\rangle$. Positions can have any value from some real interval, so this ket is sometimes written as integral over all positions on the real line:
$$
|p'\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x\rangle~ e^{ip'x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$$
Then, you're applying this ket as if it was a valid quantum state that the system can be in. This is not correct; the ket $|p\rangle$ is a mathematical object that we can work with in calculations, e.g. one can give a sense to equations such as
$$
\hat{p} |p'\rangle = p' |p'\rangle,
$$
but it does not represent a realizable quantum state. The reason is this ket is not normalizable to 1, as the expression $\langle p' | p'\rangle $ is not defined.
Realizable quantum states describing a single system have to be normalizable to 1. (There are other normalizations where the psi function need not be normalizable to 1, but those are used e.g. as statistical description of a stream of infinite number of particles with finite arrival rate).
Not only is $|p'\rangle $ not a normalizable momentum eigenket, the momentum operator does not have such an eigenket (because of the continuous character of index $p'$). So we cannot apply the usual formulation of the projection postulate to measurement of momentum(and similarly for any continuous variable). The usual formulation works for discrete variables only, e.g. spin projection.
Instead, the best we can do, is to take the result of the measurement, which is some probability distribution for $p'$, or interval $p'-\Delta p/2,p'+\Delta p/2$, and collapse to some normalized state that obeys all constraints: it is zero outside the box, and the probability distribution of momentum it implies is consistent with this result of measurement. This means the state after momentum measurement will be a superposition of many different normalized states, implying a range of momenta.
If the potential barrier is infinite, the psi function outside has to remain zero. I'm not sure it is necessary to require it is continuous on the walls; but if it is, it has to vanish on the wall also inside, so we have the restriction  $\psi(x) = 0$ for $x$ on a wall.
